# What are the possible ways to translate in MediaWiki from "backend", without an extension?

Tags: php, html, forms, translation, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki 1.33.0 website with only one extension → [ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage), with which I can have a simple contact form.

Using [HTMLForms template engine](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm) (in which the [default form-template for ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage) is written),  I have expanded the default form to include a *selection menu*.

### My problem

Selection list array keys and values of this selection menu are written in English inside `LocalSettings.php` but my site isn't primarily in the LTR English, rather, it is in the RTL Hebrew and I would like them to appear in my site's native language for end users.

### My own code pattern

```
wfLoadExtension( 'ContactPage' );
$wgContactConfig['default'] = array(
    'RecipientUser' => 'Admin', // Must be the name of a valid account which also has a verified e-mail-address added to it.
    'SenderName' => 'Contact Form on ' . $wgSitename, // "Contact Form on" needs to be translated
    'SenderEmail' => null, // Defaults to $wgPasswordSender, may be changed as required
    'RequireDetails' => true, // Either "true" or "false" as required
    'IncludeIP' => false, // Either "true" or "false" as required
    'MustBeLoggedIn' => false, // Check if the user is logged in before rendering the form
    'AdditionalFields' => array(
        'omgaselectbox' => [
            'class' => 'HTMLSelectField',
            'label' => 'Select an option',
            'options' => [
                'X' => 'X',
                'Y' => 'Y',
                'Z' => 'Z',
            ],
        ],
    ),
        // Added in MW 1.26
    'DisplayFormat' => 'table',  // See HTMLForm documentation for available values.
    'RLModules' => array(),  // Resource loader modules to add to the form display page.
    'RLStyleModules' => array(),  // Resource loader CSS modules to add to the form display page.
);
```

#### possible solutions

**1)** Writing selection list array keys and values in Hebrew (which might be a bit messy due to LTR-RTL clashings):

```
'options' => [
    'ס' => 'ס',
    'ט' => 'ט',
    'ז' => 'ז',
],
```

**2)** Translating English selection list array keys and values in client side JavaScript by some similar code:

```
document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById('select').value = 'Default';
```

### My desire

I desire an ordinal backend way to do so, and if there is one, than without an extension

[In this discussion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Vdzewdugqgzvqhi0), a MediaWiki community member recommended using [system message transclution](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:System_message#Transclusion) but the chapter dealing with it was very unclear to me; I didn't understand what this is about and how can this help in my situation.

### My question

What are the possible ways to translate in MediaWiki from "backend", without an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localisation system is working perfectly fine in the backend (php), as well in the frontend (JavaScript) parts of MediaWiki → staying with it backend is best as it is more minimal.

Assuming you take a backend only approach:

### Translation with a predefined string

If your desired translations already exist in MediaWiki (e.g. on another page of form), you can "simply" re-use the key. So, let's assume, your current additional select field definition looks like this:

```php
'Select' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => [
        'The english message' => 'value'
    ]
],
```

Then, you would change it to something like this:

```
'Select' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options-messages' => [
        'the-message-key' => 'test'
    ]
],
```

Please consider the changing of `options` into the `options-messages` key.
Also: Change the key `the-message-key` to the message key you want to reuse.

If you know a page where the message/string is used, you can just open that page with the GET option `uselang` and the value `qqx`, in order to see the message key. Example: If the string is used on the login page, simply open the login page with https://example.com/wiki/Special:Userlogin?uselang=qqx to show all the message keys used on the page.

However, **one warning** when doing that: It is mostly discouraged to re-use existing message keys, especially when they're used on other pages. The keys are translated to hundreds of languages with that specific context in mind. That could also mean, that a translation in a specific language does not fit when the string/message is used on the contact page. So I would suggest to use the second option below.

### Translation without a predefined string

Usually it will be done by extension which can provide a specific directory where the JSON files with the message key translations are saved. However, as you're "just" customizing an extension, you need a way to put in the translations for your keys.

So, first of all, let's take over the changes from above. Change your select field definition to be something like:

```
'Select' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options-messages' => [
        'my-fancy-key' => 'test'
    ]
],
```

Now, two ways to get the key translated:

**On-Wiki**

By saving the message on-wiki, the messages can also easily being changed simply by editing the respective page in the wiki. In our example, let's translate the key to english and hebrew:

English: Edit the page `MediaWiki:My-fancy-key` in your wiki and add the desired text.

Hebrew: Edit the page `MediaWiki:My-fancy-key/he` in your wiki and add the desired text.

**As part of the deployed code**

We need to register a directory with JSON files for the translations of these messages. We're using the same configuration variable as extensions would use as well, [$wgMessagesDirs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMessagesDirs), even given that we don't create an extension. Add the following line to your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgMessagesDirs['ContactPageCustomization'] = __DIR__ . '/customContactPage';
```

Now, create a directory `customContactPage` in the root folder of your MediaWiki installation and put in the following file with the following contents:

**en.json**

```
{
    "my-fancy-key": "Default"
}
```

If you want to translate to another language, create a new file with the language code you want to translate to. In hebrew it should be he, so let's create a new language file:

**he.json**

```
{
    "my-fancy-key": "ברירת מחדל"
}
```

If you then open the contact page, the message key `my-fancy-key` should be translated to the english `Default` and the same (at least based on Google Translate) for hebrew. This is a more stable way of adding custom translations, however, you now also need to take care of translating the keys into the languages you want to support on your own as well. If a key is not translated into the selected language of the user, the default language, english, is used.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use wiki pages (`MediaWiki:<message key>`) to store translations. If the translations are community-maintained, that's easier to deal with.

Comment: @Tgr Good point, I didn't think about that, don't know really, why. I'll put it into my answer as well :)

Comment: Hello @Florian and thank you for the answer. I invite you to go through my edit suggestion in which I tried to make the answer a bit less "heavy" (per my personal feeling of course) to read. I tried to shorten some phrasings and add some markup. Again thanks,

Comment: And I am sorry if I misunderstood where I read so far (is it really only two chapters as I have suggested in the edit?) I must go to sleep; I should follow this session ASAP tomorrow...

Comment: Basically: Yes, there're two possible ways of doing what you want, I accepted the edit, makes it a bit easier, yes.